# GridView button control in visual web developer 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a social network website on visual web developer, and I am using a GridView to generate a list of all Groups with a column as buttons to join this group. so how I access the action listener of the buttons and pass to it the value of the other column?

Comment: Please amend your title to be descriptive of the issue you are having. It is rather useless now. Also, please post your current code, as it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with the information given I can assume you mean listening to the event on each of the buttons generated in a gridview.

As such you would do something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)     
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)         
    {
         // Get The button from which ever cell the button is in
         Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);


    }

}

void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```